# how do you write (17456)(2)(3)(89) as a product of adjacent transpositions

Tags: group-theory

I started out by writing it as

$(16)(15)(14)(17)(2)(3)(89)$

but only $(89)$ is consecutive

where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : $(16)=(12)(23)(34)(45)(56)(45)(34)(23)(12)$.

Comment: would the answer be $(12)(23)(34)(45)(56)(67)(89)$?

Comment: No... Do something similar for $(15)$ & $(14)$ & $(17)$ ... then multiply them altogether.